# How do we call such a compactification?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $E$ be a denumerable set and let $\mathcal{F}$ be a collection of bounded functions. In the reading we had a compactification of $E$ with respect to $\mathcal{F}$, denoted by $\hat{E}_{\mathcal{F}}$.

Is there a name for this way of compactification?
I would like to look for this in books but to do so I need a name for it.

The way to construct it was rather complicated.

Comment: Is that compactification or completion? I'm not familiar with anything like that, though $\hat{\cdot}$ usually denotes some sort of completion, and I can imagine it would be completion with respect to "metrics" given by $\sup_{f\in \mathcal F}\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert$, and I see no reason for that to be compact.

Comment: In other words, I imagine that we take the function $E\to \ell^\infty(\mathcal F)$ given by the obvious formula and take the closure of the range. There's no reason for that to be compact, as the range can very well be an infinite-dimensional Banach subspace (like sequences converging to zero).

Comment: It is a compactification.

Comment: How does it work? Do we, for every $f\in\mathcal{F}$, take the smallest compact interval $I_f$ containing the range of $f$, consider the map $$\varphi \colon E \to \prod_{f\in \mathcal{F}} I_f$$ given by $\pi_f(\varphi(e)) = f(e)$, and let $\hat{E}_\mathcal{F} = \overline{\varphi(E)}$?

Comment: In this thread http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1101251/the-compactification-hate-mathcalf-is-the-alexandroff-comp-if-e-is I wrote down how the professor means it: Do not understand it, to be honest, but wrote it down.

Comment: @DanielFischer I think it is exactly what you write down.

Comment: Almost. Going by the other, before making the construction of my comment, the set of characteristic functions of elements of $E$ is added to $\mathcal{F}$, which ensures that $\varphi$ is actually an embedding (provided that $E$ is discrete). If $\mathcal{F}$ contains enough bounded functions (in particular if it contains all bounded functions on $E$, or all functions $E\to[0,1]$), what you get is (one construction of) the Stone-Čech compactification. If $\mathcal{F}$ contains only constants, you get the Alexandrov compactification. I'm not aware of a special name for this way of construction.