# The compactification $\hat{E}_{\mathcal{F}}$ is the Alexandroff-comp. if $E$ is discrete and $\mathcal{F}$ only contains constant functions

Tags: general-topology

this is my task:

> > Prove that if $E$ is a discrete set and if $\mathcal{F}$ contains only constant functions then the compactification $\hat{E}_{\mathcal{F}}$ of $E$ with respect to $\mathcal{F}$ is the Alexandroff (one point) compactification of $E$.

Could you please help me to show that? I do not know how to do that, unfortunately.

Here are the preliminaries that one does need for the task:

> > Fiven a countable infinite set $E$, by *compactification* of $E$ we mean a compact topological (Hausdorff) space $\hat{E}$ containing $E$ and such that (1.) the set $E$ is dense in $\hat{E}$ and (2.) under the induced topology, $E$ is discrete.
> >
> > The set $\hat{E}\setminus E$ is called the boundary of $E$. We consider two compactifications of $E$ as equivalent, if the identity function $E\to E$ extends to a homeomorphism between the two compactifications.
> >
> > Given a family $\mathcal{F}$ of bounded $\mathbb{R}$-valued functions on $E$, there is a standard way to associate $\mathcal{F}$ a compactification of $E$:
> >
> > **Theorem** Let $E$ be a discrete countable infinite space and let $\mathcal{F}$ be a denumerable family of bounded $\mathbb{R}$-valued functions on $E$. There exists an unique (up to homeomorphism) compactification $\hat{E}=\hat{E}_{\mathcal{F}}$ of $E$ such that (1.) every function $f\in\mathcal{F}$ extends to a continous function on $\hat{E}$ and (2.) the family $\mathcal{F}$ seperates boundary points, that is, given $\xi,\eta\in\hat{E}\setminus E$ with $\xi\neq\eta$, there exists a function $f\in\mathcal{F}$ so that $f(\eta)\neq f(\xi)$.
> >
> > **Proof** We divide the proof in two parts: First we construct such a compactification, then we show uniqueness. For $x\in E$ we write $\chi_x$ for the indicator function of $\left\{x\right\}$. We set 
> >     $$
> > \mathcal{F}^*=\mathcal{F}\cup\left\{\chi_x:x\in E\right\}.
> > $$
> >     For each $f\in\mathcal{F}^*$ there is a positive constant $c_f$ so that $-c_f\leqslant f(x)\leqslant c_f~\forall x\in E$. Consider the topological space
> >     $$
> > \Pi_{\mathcal{F}}:=\prod_{f\in\mathcal{F}^*}[-c_f,c_f]=\left\{\Phi\colon\mathcal{F}^*\to\mathbb{R}: \Phi(f)\in [-c_f,c_f]~\forall f\in\mathcal{F}^*\right\}.
> > $$
> >     The topology $\Pi_{\mathcal{F}}$ is the topology of pointwise convergence (equivalently Tychonov's topology). Namely $\Phi_n\to\Phi$ iff $\lim_{n\to\infty}\Phi_n(f)=\Phi(f)~\forall f\in\mathcal{F}^*$. A neighborhood base at $\Phi\in\Pi_{\mathcal{F}}$ is given by the finite intersections of the sets of the form
> >     $$
> > \left\{\Psi\in\Pi_{\mathcal{F}}: \lvert\Psi(f)-\Phi(f)\rvert <\varepsilon\right\}
> > $$
> >     for $f\in\mathcal{F}^*$ and $\varepsilon > 0$. We will reconstruct $E$ as discrete subset of $\Pi_{\mathcal{F}}$. For this the extension of $\mathcal{F}$ to $\mathcal{F}^*$ will be crucial. We can embed $E$ into $\Pi_{\mathcal{F}}$ via the map $i\colon E\to\Pi_{\mathcal{F}}$ defined by $i(x)=\Phi_x$ where $\Phi_x(f)=f(x)$ for $f\in\mathcal{F}^*$. The map $\Phi_x$ is sometimes called the *Gelfand transform*. If $x$ and $y$ are distinct elements of $E$, then
> >     $$
> > \Phi_x(\chi_x)=\chi_x(x)=1\neq 0=\chi_x(y)=\Phi_y(\chi_x).
> > $$
> >     Therefore the inclusion map is injective. Moreover, the neighborhood
> >     $$
> > \left\{\Psi\in\Pi_{\mathcal{F}}:\lvert\Psi(\chi_x)-\Phi_x(\chi_x)\rvert < 1\right\}
> > $$
> >     does not contain the function $\Phi_y$ for $y\in E\setminus\left\{x\right\}$. This means that $i(E)$ under the induced topology is a discrete subset of $\Pi_{\mathcal{F}}$. Therefore, we identify $i(E)$ and $E$. We define $\hat{E}$ to be the closure of $E$ or more precisely $i(E)$. In particular, we have shown the existence of a compactification of $E$ dependent on $\mathcal{F}$.

*I do not write down the proof of the uniqueness here and neither the proof that the constructed compactification fullfills the two properties.*

Comment: You need to show that the "boundary of $E$" contains only one point. By the theorem, the family $\mathcal{F}$ separates boundary points.

Comment: Suppose $x,y\in\hat{E}\setminus E$, $x\neq y$. Then there is a $f\in\mathcal{F}$ such that $f(x)\neq f(y)$. My first thought was that this cannot be because $f$ is constant - but isn't it only defined resp. constant on $E$? On the other hand, $f$ can be extended to a continous function $f'$ on $\hat{E}$ and in order to be continous $f'$ must be constant with the same constant as $f$, or?

Comment: Part of the theorem is that all $f\in \mathcal{F}$ extend continuously to $\hat{E}$. Since $E$ is dense in $\hat{E}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff, ...

Comment: I think I do understand. But do not know how to write it down correctly with the density and Hausdorff.

Comment: That is my problem is to show correctly that $f'$, which denotes the continous extension of $f$, is constant on $\hat{E}\setminus E$.

Comment: It is clear that a constant function defined on a subspace can be continuously extended to a constant function on the entire space. So the question is: is a continuous extension of $f\colon E\to \mathbb{R}$ to $\hat{E}$ unique, or can there be different continuous extensions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20184/discussion-between-math12-and-daniel-fischer).

Comment: In the chat I tried to argue why $f'(x)=f'(y)$. Can you have a look, please?